# Can @FunctionalInterfaces have default methods?

Tags: java, java-8

Why can't I create a `@FunctionalInterface` with a default method implementation?

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyInterface {
    default boolean authorize(String value) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can have default methods in a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) but its contract requires you to provide one single abstract method (or SAM). Since a default method have an implementation, it's not abstract.

> Conceptually, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method.
> Since default methods have an implementation, they are not abstract.

and

> If a type is annotated with this annotation type, compilers are
> required to generate an error message unless:
>
> The type is an interface type and not an annotation type, enum, or
> class.
>
> The annotated type satisfies the requirements of a functional
> interface.

Here you don't satisfy the functional interface's requirement, so you need to provide one abstract method. For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyInterface {

    boolean authorize(int val);
    
    default boolean authorize(String value) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that if you declare an abstract method overriding one of a public method from the Object's class it doesn't count, because any implementation of this interface will have an implementation of those methods through at least the Object's class. For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyInterface {

    default boolean authorize(String value) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean equals(Object o);
}
```

does not compile.

Comment: The last sentence is very misleading. You probably mean “abstract methods whose signature matches a method declared in `java.lang.Object`”. The important point is that the *declaration* in a concrete class has precedence, even if a subclass overrides it with an `abstract` method. That `abstract` method of a non-`interface` class still has precedence over `interface` methods, even if the latter are not `abstract`.

Comment: @Holger Yes this is what I meant. I updated it to make it more clear.

Comment: @Holger, Seems to me that, `java.lang.Object` is _like_ an interface with some `default` methods

Comment: @mjalil except that `default` methods can not be `protected` nor `final`. And, as already said, methods from a concrete class like `Object` have precedence over interface methods.

Answer (score 14):

A *functional interface* is an `interface` having a single **abstract** method. The entire purpose of defining functional interfaces is to enable the implementation of the single abstract method via lambda expressions which will effectively override that method which makes providing a `default` implementation for it pointless.

Having an `interface` consisting entirely of `default` methods raises multiple problems. There is the technical problem that the compiler can’t decide for a lambda expression which method to implement when there are multiple `default` methods and there is the semantic problem that an `interface` consisting entirely of `default` methods is not `abstract`. You can’t instantiate this default behavior as you can’t instantiate `interface`s and are forcing programmers to create concrete classes just to invoke the default behavior, which, since interfaces are stateless, could be provided by a singleton instead:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyInterface {
    static MyInterface DEFAULT = s->true;
    boolean authorize(String value);
}
```

---

Note that you can have interfaces extending a functional interface and providing a default method, if you need. Still, if this results in creating an `interface` having no abstract methods I would question the design. You may compare with the [discussion about marker interfaces with `default` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26723994/2711488). If the sub-interface will have different abstract methods than the functional interface, it’s a different story. There might be real use cases for this, but these sub-interfaces will also demonstrate why they shouldn’t be mixed with the functional base `interface` as a lambda expression will always implement the **abstract** method.

Comment: `default` methods in functional interfaces isn't pointless. It [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27252163/2377645) to handle checked exceptions for non throwing interfaces like `Supplier`.

Comment: @Ivan you should try to read correctly before commenting. No-one said that default methods were pointless. Having *only* default methods would be pointless. You should read and understand the question first, as answers are given in that specific context.

Answer (score 9):

That's because `@FunctionalInterface` can have default methods, as many as you want. For example, consider the `java.util.Function` interface. It contains two default methods: `compose` and `andThen`. But there should be exactly one non-default method. Otherwise how compiler would know which of your default methods should be mapped to lambda?

Answer (score -3):

I just want to add a few more points.

1. We can have any number of **Abstract** method in FuntionalInterface.
2. We can also have any number of **Static** method in FuntionalInterface.
3. We can also declare an abstract method overriding one of a public method from the Object's class but there must be some other custom abstract method in this functional interface too as shown in below code

   @FunctionalInterface
       public interface SAM {
           public void helloSam();

   ```
       default void xyz() {
           System.out.println("xyz");
       }

       static void abc() {
           System.out.println("abc");
       }

       static void abc1() {
           System.out.println("abc1");
       }

       default void xyz1() {
           System.out.println("xyz1");
       }

        boolean equals(Object o);
   }
   ```

Comment: Would having these method add some value or solve something? This isn't aligned with the purpose of functional interface which is to facilitate lambda expressions isn't it?

Comment: We can have only one Abstract method in a FunctionalInterface. Point #1 is misleading